# Touch based volume out for windows 10 touchscreen

Tags: volume-control

There is a program called [VolumeOut](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Tweak/System-Tweak/VolumeOut.shtml) that gradually decreases your computer's volume over a set period of time (which is great before bedtime). It works decently but has two issues:

1. The buttons are very small, so on my Surface Pro 3 tablet it's hard to use without a mouse or stylus.
2. My experience has been that the first time you start the countdown, the volume will immediately go to 0 and you must redo the process and it tends to work on the second time. If it could work the first time, this would be ideal.

Is there a Windows 10 touch based program that does something similar to the above?

Specifications:

- I would be willing to spend about 10$
- Windows 10 touch based app, meaning that the buttons have to be big enough that a fat finger can use it easily.